# Discrete maximization of geometric mean - reference request

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, combinatorial-optimization, extremal-graph-theory

This is a follow-up to my previous MO question:

[A discrete optimization problem related to the AM-GM inequality](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443444/a-discrete-optimization-problem-related-to-the-am-gm-inequality)

Let $n,k$ be integers such that $1\le k\le n$. Define the quantity
$$
P(n,k):=\max\ a_1\cdots a_k\ ,
$$
where the maximum is taken over $k$-tuples of integers $(a_1,\ldots,a_k)$ which are $\ge 1$ and which sum up to $n$.

One can write the explicit formula
$$
P(n,k)=\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor\right)^{k-n+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor}
\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor+1\right)^{n-k\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor}\ .
$$

I would like to learn as much as possible about what is known in the literature regarding the quantity $P(n,k)$. For instance, in the other MO question, a connection to the [Turán graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem) was mentioned. Any references, which study $P(n,k)$ or where that quantity plays a significant role, would be appreciated.
I tried to do a search on the web, but I mostly got links to finance articles about portfolio maximization which did not quite suit my needs.

Answer (score 4):

If you maximize $P(n,k)$ over $k$ you obtain the OEIS sequence [A000792](https://oeis.org/A000792), which appears in a variety of contexts (maximal size of an Abelian subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$, maximum number of maximal cliques possible in a graph with $n$ vertices, largest number of complexity $n$, ...)

Comment: Thank you! Looking at the OEIS page opens up a whole chunk of the related literature I was not aware of.

Comment: Just posted an article related to this question: https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.07358